# After replication there are lots of ClientAbortException in solr side

Tags: solr

I have a SOLR master and slaves using SOLR 4.1. The size of the index is not that big so the replication takes about 30 seconds (this is full refresh not incremental update). A big problem I have is that whenever there is a replication (once a day), there are lots of timeout errors in the client side and there are lots of ClientAbortException in tomcat/solr side like this:

```
SEVERE: null:ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
```

As far as I understand, this exception happens when the client is no longer listening to. Since there are timeouts in the client side, I am guessing some kind of disconnection is happening somehow?

In my case there is a loadbalancer sitting between the client and the solr slaves. When I looked at JMX GC log, there is a big spike of "ConcurrentMarkSweep collection time" metric. I guess either this GC is causing some incoming query queued up or something is wrong in the loadbalancer or tomcat?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I am wondering if this is because of lack of warming up or too much warming up in different caches. I am using DocumentCache, FilterCache and FieldValueCache with autowarmCount setting but I don't know how to optimize the these values

Answer (score 0):

Solr 4.1 is known to be buggy with replication. Try the latest version.